# Why is my modulo operator returning a doubled block size for an input of 1 byte?

Tags: python, modulo, floor-division

The idea here is to create a function called calculator that takes an input and compares it to a variable. Compare file size to block size, and if there's a remainder, double the block size to accommodate usage. My problem is, with an input of 1, I still get 8192? Yet the other calculations come out correct. I know that floor division only yields an integer, not a float (which I thought may be a better way to do this because I wanted the real number) yet when I try to float it, I get the same returns. I've also tried floating elsewhere, with either incorrect or the same results as above. When I reversed the order of the modulo, the answer appears correct but I am informed this is wrong and told to do it more like what you see here, with floor division and modulo in this order.

So my question is, why am I getting 8192 with an input of 1, but the rest are right?

```
def calculator(somedata):                 # calculator function, 'somedata' is the input
    blocksize = 4096                      # what block size on the partition
                                          # calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
    fullblock = somedata // blocksize     # floor division will give back only the integer yes?
                                          # modulo to check whether there's any remainder
    bytesremain = somedata % blocksize    # which will say 1 or None unless I float yes?
                                          # return the block usage based on byte count?
    if bytesremain > 0:                   # if there's anything left over in the bytesremain
      return(blocksize * 2)               # double the block usage to 2
    return blocksize                      # otherwise return the block usage

print(calculator(1))                      # Should be 4096 
print(calculator(4096))                   # Should be 4096 
print(calculator(4097))                   # Should be 8192 
print(calculator(6000))                   # Should be 8192
```

Comment: wouldn't you want `blocksize * fullblock ` at some point? Right now you are returning either `4096` or double that, you are never multiplying that by how many blocks are actually needed or anything.

Comment: `1 % 4096` is `1`. That's greater than 0. What did you expect?

Comment: `1 % 4096` is 1. Then `1 > 0` is true, so you return `2 * 4096`

Comment: If something doesn't quite fit into an integer number of blocks, you only need to *add one block* to make it fit, not double the number of blocks!

Comment: OK I can see that mathematical aspect of the 1 modulo against 4096 being 1 and doubling the output. Thank you for pointing out the blocksize * fullblock, I didn't overlook that but they're only giving me so much room to work with, and so many areas to edit. Thank you for your input guys I'll work on this

Comment: Jason I may not be adding the blocks correctly when I tried that, I was getting 4097

Comment: Its common to add a block to accommodate the remaining partial block but you are doubling the block size itself? You code does exactly what you want it to do: doubles the block size whenever there is a remainder. Perhaps your requirement is wrong. Are you trying to calculate the number of fixed size blocks needed to fit a given size?

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for:

```py
def calculator(somedata):
    blocksize = 4096
    fullblock = (somedata-1) // blocksize 
    return blocksize*(fullblock+1)
```

Comment: I appreciate the input; I am able to get the correct output without the -1/+1 just by returning  ```blocksize*(fullblock+1)```. Thanks!

Comment: @sincera: If you do that, you're adding an extra block unconditionally, even when it isn't needed.

Comment: I see that now, thanks. Still doesn't satisfy the instructor; thanks for you time anyways guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096

    # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
    full_blocks = filesize//block_size

    # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
    partial_block_remainder = filesize%block_size

    # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
    # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
    # to store your data.
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        return (full_blocks*4096)+4096
    return (full_blocks*4096)

print(calculate_storage(1))    # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4096)) # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4097)) # Should be 8192
print(calculate_storage(6000)) # Should be 8192
```

Comment: Can you please explain why do you support this solution and what are the improvements from the original post?

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
    full_blocks = filesize // block_size
    # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
    partial_block_remainder = filesize % block_size
    # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
    # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
    # to store your data.
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        return block_size*(full_blocks+1)
    return block_size

print(calculate_storage(1))    # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4096)) # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4097)) # Should be 8192
print(calculate_storage(6000)) # Should be 8192
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
full_blocks = filesize // block_size 

partial_block_remainder = block_size % filesize
```

Comment: If you give an answer, provide the necessary explanation to the PO (and everyone else who is reading the question) in terms of where the error was and what lines you are correcting to fix it. In its current form, your answer is not very informative.

Answer (score 0):

```
Something else to remember here
is the format of modulo arithmetic. The divisor is always to
the right of the modulo operator. E.g.- 2 = 6 % 4 <- This is
the divisor.   

 def calculate_storage(filesize):
        block_size = 4096
        # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
        full_blocks = filesize//block_size
        # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
        partial_block_remainder = block_size%filesize
        # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
        # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
        # to store your data.
        if partial_block_remainder > 0:
            return block_size*2
        return block_size
    
    print(calculate_storage(1))    # Should be 4096
    print(calculate_storage(4096)) # Should be 4096
    print(calculate_storage(4097)) # Should be 8192
    print(calculate_storage(6000)) # Should be 8192
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
    full_blocks = filesize // block_size
    # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
    partial_block_remainder = filesize % block_size
    # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
    # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
    # to store your data.
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        return (full_blocks + 1) * block_size 
    return full_blocks * block_size

print(calculate_storage(1))    # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4096)) # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4097)  # Should be 8192
print(calculate_storage(6000)) # Should be 8192
```

1. We use floor division to keep a record in the memory to see how many blocks would be needed (4096 blocks)
2. Then we check for any reminder blocks that would be left when we are checking the block sizes. This is because although block size is 1 but if another 0.5 of a block size is needed, one block would not be able accompany it.
3. Finally we create two arguments. First one is if the partial block remainder is more than zero and full blocks is more than or equal to one, the block size should be doubled.

The computational thinking here is that, since the requirement is to add an additional block size of 4096 in an instance where there is a partial_block_remainder, each output we receive which falls into the partial_block_remainder needs to be raised by a further 4096.

If we worry about the (calculate_storage(1)), since the full_blocks would give an output of zero but the partial_block_remainder is available, it will show as 4096.

Comment: Please consider adding a description alongside your code so that we would understand WH Y it solves the op's issue

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
    full_blocks = filesize // block_size
    # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
    partial_block_remainder = filesize % block_size
    # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
    # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
    # to store your data.
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        return full_blocks * block_size + block_size
    return full_blocks * block_size
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    full_blocks = filesize//block_size
    if filesize > block_size:
        return block_size*2
    return block_size
```

I think this is the best solution for all cases in filesize!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
<pre><code>
def cstorage(fsize):
    bsize = 4096
    fblocks = fsize // bsize

    pbremainder = fsize % bsize

    if pbremainder > 0:
        return bsize*(fblocks+1)
    return bsize*fblocks

print(cstorage(1))  
print(cstorage(4096))
print(cstorage(4097)) 
print(cstorage(6000))
</pre></code>
```

Comment: Hello, please always provide an explanation of what your code does.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the following:

```
import math
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    full_blocks = math.ceil(filesize/block_size)
    return full_blocks*block_size


print(calculate_storage(1))    
print(calculate_storage(4096)) 
print(calculate_storage(4097)) 
print(calculate_storage(9000))
```

Comment: Please write that part in a comment instead: "I think it works to give the same answer, but I was hoping that someone could validate if this is correct. Please let me know. Thanks!"